# How to make Linux installation verifiable/auditable?

Tags: linux, nixos, audit, verification

A major goal of open source is being able to audit/verify the software you run. But the moment we use that software hosted by a third-party we need to trust them..

If I ran an OSS service on a Linux box that I wanted to make 100% transparent, is there a way for me to offer *anyone* to verify the box is running what I say it is running?

Some ideas that come to mind:

- have a read-only user that can ssh into the box and execute exactly one command to verify the list of installed packages
- use NixOS which uses deterministic installs (I think called generations), could such an "audit" user access the box and cryptographically verify installed packages and configurations?

Are there any tools that can help with this? Not an expert :) Any suggestions more than welcome.

Comment: I think my question was clear and asked kindly. To the downvoter: we both know why you did it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. Reproducible builds + secure boot. Solved problems!

Your verification command idea, however, is completely pointless: your usert would have to trust that the command doesn't lie. At which point they could just as well trust that any other piece of software is what they expect it to be.

So, as said, secure boot to make the hardware verify your signature-verifying software loader is bitwise identical with what you let your users see, and reproducible builds so that they can see what is loaded by building it from source and getting bitwise identical software images, which they can compare with the signatures of what your software loader loads.

You will still need to trust the hardware to execute exactly the software it is given, and not something else. Since that is honestly not how modern mainboards nor CPUs work, and since that part hides significant amount of unauditable software, you'd need to be in a position like Google or the DoD in the face of your hardware vendors and be powerful enough a buyer to negotiate for all firmware to be supplied to you.

Comment: A lot to digest, thanks! Reproducible builds is the word I was missing :)

Comment: Assuming we trust the hardware, imagine I want to resell a VPS with a Bitcoin Core node on Debian/NixOS (there are reproducible builds for all) installed and ready to use.. is this even feasible?  How would the process be for a customer to verify?

Comment: Sorry, you have a killword in your comment. Not helping with burning the planet :)

Comment: Sure! I used Bitcoin Core just as an example.

Comment: Btw burning the planet sounds a bit reactionary. I would love to invite you to read (in depth, not mainstream headlines) on how mining is actually benefitting the environment. 

But even if it didn't our opinions don't really matter because Bitcoin is truly unstoppable.

Comment: dude. You're converting electrical energy into heat and anyway but nominally worthless tokens. The whole … stuff about wasting energy magically helping the environment is 1a nonsense. I've read stuff. It's not only delusional, it really needs someone who *wants* to believe: "by buying electricity where it's cheap (i.e. where coal is cheap) we actually reduce emissions", that really needs someone who's left logic behind.  Seriously, quit it now. This is all hogwash.

Comment: 1) "Worthless tokens": could it be that you don't understand what makes money, money? and if for any reason you believe the ptrodollar system backs "money" - well it is objectively far worse for the environment.

2) "where coal is cheap": Coal can actually be transported to where there is energy demand, so no, stranded energy is way cheaper and that is where miners tends to move. Also mining is the only rational way to support a 100% renewable grid because it incentivizes investment by reducing curtailment.

Civilizations advance when they use more energy, not less. The future is bright :)

Comment: I give up. You've really drank the coolaid. Listen to yourself! "Mining is the only rational way to support a renewable grid": it would be funny, if you didn't mean it seriously. The casualty you think you refer here doesn't exist. At all. It's just not there. People say that as if it is a fact, but as an electrical engineer with enough friends in smart grid planning, these people plainly just lie, or they believe truthisms as if they were facts without any critical thinking. Sadly, as in where that idiom " drinking the coolaid" comes from, that's a very damaging act.

Comment: Beautiful coincidence, me too, and my electrical engineer friend Lyn also argues bitcoin energy usage is not a problem: https://www.lynalden.com/bitcoin-energy/ - do you have anything to share that could help me understand your point of view?

Comment: Sure. It's called Newtons second law of thermodynamics and says that once you converted electricity into heat with zero human benefit, you cannot reduce the amount of heat you produced, no matter how many brain bending exercises you do. I'll not discuss this any further.

Comment: It's the best monetary technology humanity has ever seen, and money is the cornerstone of civilization, therefore it has massive human benefit. This can be difficult to understand even for very intelligent people so don't worry. Good luck!

Comment: yes yes. Drink your cool aid.